# PrimeNG remove row selection from table in single selection

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I tried use Table - CRUD from PRIMENG but, i've the same problem just like the example. The selection continues even when i close the dialog.
I wanna clear that selection after i close the dialog. 
i has tried even with @ViewChild references from class Table.

```
@ViewChild('dtUserEmp') table: Table;
```

TagID

```
<p-table #dtUserEmp selectionMode="single"
       [(selection)]="usuarioEmpresaSelection"
       (onLazyLoad)="lazyLoadingNat($event)"
       (onRowSelect)="rowSelect($event)"
       (onRowUnselect)="rowUnselect($event)"
       dataKey="empresa"...>... </p-table>
```

Link from documentation that i following:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/crud

Comment: They could have solved it by subscribing on `(onHide)` for `p-dialog` and clearing selection... I don't know if you use `p-dialog`, but you can try something similar...

Comment: i tried to clean: selectionKeys and selection with @ViewChild('dtUserEmp') too.

Comment: I'm using ngx-bootstrap for the dialog. I've tried it (onHide) but it doesn't work.

Comment: @miselking i agree with you.

Comment: Thanks :) . I don't think `ngx-bootstrap` dialog has `onHide`, can you provide that code as well (code for dialog)?

Comment: I close the dialog. But when a come back to my DataTable.The row still marked.  I also tried calling the method: this.table.handleRowClick($event) on close the dialog. But it still not working.

Comment: Estou tentando fazer evento onRowSelect da tabela mas, nenhuma resposta positiva.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a best way to do it but I can tell you the approach how you can achieve this. Later you can do it in better way. You also see some error in console but you can handle them easily and it will not break your app.
So lets break your requirement like below:

Now whenever you will click on any row class **ui-state-highlight** is getting added. So the key is remove this class whenever we click on save.

Suppose below is my table and I have given #dd as reference to this table.

```
<p-table #dd [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" 
  selectionMode="multiple" 
  [(selection)]="selectedCars2" 
  [metaKeySelection]="true">
...
</p-table>
```

Now whenever you call the save button just pass the **dd** inside that or you can use the **dd** as @ViewChild in your component.

```
<button (click)="save(dd)">Save</button>
or
import { Table } from '../../../../node_modules/primeng/components/table/table';
export class TableComponent{
 @ViewChild('dd') dd: Table;
 save(){
 }
```

}

Now in component file inside your save function do the below:
This is where you will find all the row **e.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].children**

```
save(e:any){
    let element = e.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].children;
    for(let key in element){
        (element[key].classList).remove('ui-state-highlight');
    }
  }
```

This will remove the class from the row in table.
You can print the value and can try to fetch the value dynamically for children[2]. Which I hardCoded to 2. You need to search for **tbody**. I hope this position is fixed for the table. So hardcoded will work everywhere. Though you can make it dynamic.

Comment: This is the second time I get your help. Thanks a lot @DirtyMind

Comment: @DirtyMind i have the same scenario. And i did same as what you described. But 'ui-state-highlight' isnt removed and I still see the highlight. Do you know why?

Comment: @JNPW Are you getting any error in console ? Check if you are getting the right value here in you version of primeng `e.tableViewChild.nativeElement.children[2].children;`. Manually you have to check wether children[2] is correct one or not?